# How to pass a name of an argument to the variable names of a function

Tags: python, list, variables, arguments, names

I'm only starting getting into a python from #C and I have this question that I wasn't able to find an answer to, maybe I wasn't able to form a question right

I need this to create two lists when using:**load(positives)** and **load(negatives)**, positives is a path to the file. From #C I'm used to use this kind of structure for not copy the same code again just with another variable, eg. what if I would need 5 lists. With this code i'm only able to access the self.dictionary variable but in no way self.positives and self.negatives

I get error AttributeError: 'Analyzer' object has no attribute 'positives' at line 'for p in self.positives:'

MAIN QUESTION IS: how to make self.dictionary = [] to create list variables from the argument name - self.positives and self.negatives which i need later in code

---

```
def load(self, dictionary):

    i = 0
    self.dictionary = []
    with open(dictionary) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            #some more code
            self.dictionary.append(0)
            self.dictionary[i] = line
            i+=1

#later in code
    for p in self.positives:
        if text == p:
        score += 1
    for p in self.negatives:
        if text == p:
        score -= 1

#structure of a program:
class Analyzer():
    def load()
    def init()
         load(positives)
         load(negatives)
    def analyze()
        for p in self.positives
```

Comment: Did you define `load` as a method or a function outside a class? I suspect the later.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. How exactly is your code not working?

Comment: what is dictionary ? what kind of values does it hold ?

Comment: dictionary argument gets positives and negatives - which holds the path to file, so i guess a string

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from the question, you are trying to create 2 lists. You first have to declare them like this:

```
FirstList = [ ]
SecondList = [ ]
```

Then take whatever value you want to add to the list and append it like this:

```
SecondList.append("The thing you want in the list")
```

by the end of the code your lists should be filled with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write self.dictionary and expect python to convert it to self.positives or self.negatives.
Instead of positives, insert self.positives and self.negatives into the function and use those.

Answer (score 0):

Took long enough to figure it out:

All it took was to return a self.dictionary from load, and assign it in init as self.positives = self.load(positives):

```
#structure of a program:
class Analyzer():
def load()
    return self.dictionary
def init()
    self.positives = self.load(positives)
    self.negatives = self.load(negatives)
def analyze()
    for p in self.positives
```